# how to read date and time on ecmwf file

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, data-analysis

I have global datasets in netcdf file. Time information on data file is:

```
<type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int32 time(time)
    units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0
    long_name: time
    calendar: gregorian
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (5875,)
filling off
```

when I extracted time from file, I got this array:

```
array([ 876600,  876624,  876648, ..., 1017528, 1017552, 1017576], dtype=int32)
```

my question is how to convert this array into proper date format?
[Note: This is a daily data sets and number in an array is corresponding to an hours from 1900-01-01]

Comment: You mean date from 1900-01-01

Comment: @KHELILI, I mean corresponding date for this array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is using [netCDF4 num2date](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.num2date)

```
import netCDF4

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('./foo.nc', 'r')
time = ncfile.variables['time']
dates = netCDF4.num2date(time[:], time.units, time.calendar)
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got error " 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'units'

Comment: now I understand, it works :) , I put [:] after time so it was not working. perfect :)

Comment: @bikuser, that's right - the `units` and `calendar` attributes can be accessed only by not including the `[:]` after the variable read in. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

You could:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

hours = [ 876600,  876624,  876648, 1017528, 1017552, 1017576]
base = date(1900, 1, 1)
for hour in hours:
    base + timedelta(hours=hour)

2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04
2016-01-30
2016-01-31
2016-02-01
```

Use `datetime` instead of `date` if you want `hour` etc info.

Or using a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(hours, columns=['hours'])
df['date'] = df.hours.apply(lambda x: base + timedelta(hours=x))

     hours        date
0   876600  2000-01-02
1   876624  2000-01-03
2   876648  2000-01-04
3  1017528  2016-01-30
4  1017552  2016-01-31
5  1017576  2016-02-01
```

Comment: Thank you so much, You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

The soln using `.apply` is horribly inefficient, not to mention non-idiomatic and ugly. pandas already has built-in vectorized methods of doing timedelta conversions.

```
In [17]: hours = [ 876600,  876624,  876648, 1017528, 1017552, 1017576]*10000

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(hours, columns=['hours'])

In [19]: %timeit df.hours.apply(lambda x: base + timedelta(hours=x))
10 loops, best of 3: 74.2 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit pd.to_timedelta(df.hours, unit='h') + Timestamp(base)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop

In [23]: (pd.to_timedelta(df.hours, unit='h') + Timestamp(base)).head()
Out[23]: 
0   2000-01-02
1   2000-01-03
2   2000-01-04
3   2016-01-30
4   2016-01-31
Name: hours, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ar = xr.open_dataset('xyz.nc') #read the data downloaded from ECMEF with xarray 
conv = ar.to_dataframe() % convert it to data frame 
driex = conv.reset_index()
df = driex.set_index('time').resample('D').mean()  # hourly to daily average 

No=df.no #read attributes (eg: Nitrogen monoxide)
so2=df.so2
```

Comment: Explain your code please. Code only is not an answer.